# How do I change the look/feel of Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio

Note: moved from programmer stackexchange

After upgrading to the latest version of Visio, I noticed that when selecting a shape, the corners, rotate handle, etc no longer look like they did in my old version. I liked it better before. Does anyone know how to change the look/feel back?

Edit: from 2010 -> 2016 version

Comment: It may be helpful to list the version of visio you have now and the one you came from to get a proper answer.

Comment: Many users of Visio 2010 would like to get it back to looking how it was in Visio 2007 and previous!